# Switching between multiple pages in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, midlet

Good Day. i am new to J2ME and just started to build an application. The challenge i have is, i have a single MIDlet and multiple pages (forms) in different classes and going back to former pages, particularly the midlet is an issue. from the AirtimeTopUp page, i'm trying go back to SignedIn. But i keep getting errors and i'm a little confufsed on what to do next.

```
  public class AirtimeTopUp extends Form implements CommandListener {

  private Command mNextCommand;
  private Command mBackCommand;
  private SignedIn dis;
  private SignedIn startUp;
  private List list;
  private ChoiceGroup choiceGroup;
  private Display displayMngr = null;
  MyPiDONumber form3 = null;

  public AirtimeTopUp(SignedIn dis) {

      super("Top Up");
      this.dis = dis;
      choiceGroup = new ChoiceGroup(null, Choice.EXCLUSIVE);
      choiceGroup.append("My PiDO Number", null);
      choiceGroup.append("Other Number", null);
      mNextCommand = new Command("Continue", Command.SCREEN, 1);
      mBackCommand = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 2);
      append(choiceGroup);
      this.setCommandListener(this);
      addCommand(mNextCommand);
      addCommand(mBackCommand);
      Display.getDisplay(dis).setCurrent(this);
  }

  public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
      if (c == mNextCommand) {
          int index = choiceGroup.getSelectedIndex();
          if (choiceGroup.getString(index).startsWith("My")) {
               Display.getDisplay(dis).setCurrent(new MyPiDONumber(dis));
          } else if (choiceGroup.getString(index).startsWith("Other Number")) {

            }
      } else {
          if (c == mBackCommand) {
              Display.getDisplay(dis).setCurrent(new SignedIn(dis));
          }
      }
  }
```

}

And this is my MIDlet class:

```
 public class SignedIn extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {
   private List mList;
   private Command mExitCommand, mNextCommand;
   private Display displayMngr = null;
   private AirtimeTopUp airtime = null;


public SignedIn(){
  String[] stringElements = { "Airtime TopUp", "Transfer", "Cashout", "Balance", "Pay Bills", "Mini Statement", "Account Settings", "PayCom Contacts", "cCare" };
  //Image[] imageElements = { loadImage("airplane.png"), loadImage("car.png"), loadImage("hotel.png") };
  mList = new List("Welcome!", List.IMPLICIT, stringElements, null);

  mNextCommand = new Command("Next", Command.SCREEN, 0);
  mExitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
  mList.addCommand(mNextCommand);
  mList.addCommand(mExitCommand);
  mList.setCommandListener(this);
}

public void startApp() {
    Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(mList);
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable s) {
    if (c == mNextCommand || c == List.SELECT_COMMAND) {
        int index = mList.getSelectedIndex();
        if(mList.getString(index).startsWith("Airtime")){
            new AirtimeTopUp(this);
        }
        else if(mList.getString(index).startsWith("Transfer")){
            Alert alert = new Alert("Your selection", "You chose " + mList.getString(index) + ".", null, AlertType.INFO);
            alert.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
            displayMngr.setCurrent(alert, mList);
        }
    }
    else if (c == mExitCommand)
        notifyDestroyed();
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: void method cannot be passed through.

Comment: you have "new SignedIn(dis)", I don't see a constructor for SignedIn that accepts a SignedIn object. Although that is a compile time error.